# sql server select by datetime

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
   Select * From MyTable where Email_Date = @Email_Date

    --Email_Date = 2012-05-13 10:49:48.050
```

SQL Server 2008 R2.  Email_Date is datetime field.  No records are returned.  How do I pass in datetime as a filter.

Comment: what is the Email_Date stored as - a timestamp, date, datetime?

Comment: The way of passing the argument may depend on your preferred method of query invocation. Is your SELECT statement (part of) a stored procedure? Or do you use formal parameters when calling it from the client application? Or do you usually concatenate the parameters in instead when constructing your queries?

Comment: Also, have you tried running your query with that particular argument in SQL Server Management Studio or a similar tool? Has it never returned any rows? There might just be none matching the filter.

Comment: I agree with Andriy here. Select the datetime column of the record you are expecting to see along with you Email_Date using a consistent. For example SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), Email_Date, 109) and SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), YourOtherDate, 109) <- Note I had to leave the at symbols off the variables due to SO comments thinking I was replying to someone. You get the idea though

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Email_Date_Str varchar(10)
SET @Email_Date_Str = CONVERT(varchar(10), @Email_Date, 120)
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), Email_Date, 120) = @Email_Date_Str
```

Comment: I need the full datetime passed in (2012-05-13 10:49:48.050) not just the date